# String Replace in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have string named `File_Test_name_1285931677.xml`. `File` is the common word and `1285931677` is a random number.
I want to remove `File_` and `_1285931677.xml`, i.e. prefix up to first `_` and suffix from  last `_` on.

Comment: You should elaborate a bit adding contest, because the literal answer to your question is a trivial `str_replace`

Comment: Is there any pattern or the file is always named like this?

Comment: I want to remove  First string Before _ and last string after_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [`explode`](http://php.net/explode), [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode):

```
implode('_', array_slice(explode('_', $str), 1, -1))
```

With `explode` the string gets cut into parts at `_` so that the result is an array like this:

```
array('File', 'Test', 'name', '1285931677.xml')
```

With `array_slice` everything from the second to the second last is grabbed, e.g.:

```
array('Test', 'name')
```

This is then put back together using `implode`, resulting in:

```
Test_name
```

---

Another approach would be to use [`strrpos`](http://php.net/strrpos) and [`substr`](http://php.net/substr):

```
substr($str, 5, strrpos($str, '_')-5)
```

Since `File_` has fixed length, we can use 5 as the starting position. `strrpos($str, '_')` returns the position of the last occurrence of `_`. When subtracting 5 from that position, we get the distance from the fifth character to the position of the last occurrence that we use as the length of the substring.

Answer (score 3):

I would be lazy and use:

```
$file_name = "File_Test_name_1285931677.xml";
preg_replace("/^File_Test_name_\d+\.xml$/", "Test_name.xml", $filename);
```

This is provided you always want to call it Test_name. If Test_name changes:

```
preg_replace("/^File_(.+)_\d+\.xml$/", "$1.xml", $file_name);
```

EDIT (Again):
Reread your update. You'll want the second example.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to replace as string [replace_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is the way to go

```
$str = "File_Test_name_1285931677.xml";
echo str_replace("File_Test_name_1285931677.xml",'Test_name', $str);
```

If you want to rename a file you need to use [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php):

```
rename("/directors_of_file/File_Test_name_1285931677.xml", "Test_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = preg_replace('/^File_(.*?)_\d+\.xml$/', '$1', $filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use substr but clearly a str_replace with pattern matching would be better:

```
$file = "File_test_name_12345.xml";
$new_file = substr($file,strpos($file,'_')+1,strrpos($file,'_')-strpos($file,'_')).substr($file,strrpos($file,'.'));
```